# Соединение с БД средствами ООП PHP

Tags: ооп, php, база-данных

Как лучше соединяться с БД?
Синглтон или как лучше? Пример готовый не помешал бы.

Comment: -22 репутации 
15% принятых

есть смысл отвечать этому пользователю?

Answer (score 3):

Чем вас PDO не устраивает? Хорошее решение на ООП. Если я вас не правильно понял, перестройте ваш вопрос в более понятную форму.

Comment: @Сергей, 100%

Answer (score 2):

[Doctrine DBAL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/index.html) - хорошая штука :)

Answer (score 1):

[DbSimple](http://dklab.ru/lib/DbSimple/) вполне годный пример.

Answer (score 1):

[Introduction to PHP PDO](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html).